# How can I avoid Stream<X> return type method in JpaRepository loading all data into memory with EclipseLink JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring-data, eclipselink

We are using Spring data 2.4.4 + EclipseLink 2.7.0 (JPA 2.2) in our project.

Recently, we are developing a function allowing user downloading data by xlsx, and when I test interface with large dataset, it ran out of memory (`OutOfMemoryError`) unsurprisingly. So we are considering using `Stream` tpye method in `JpaRepository` expecting EclipseLink will return a `Stream` implemented by `CursoredStream` or `ScrollableCursor`. However, it seems to behave just like getting a `List`.

To verify, I defined a method that would fetch all job orders from db:

```java
@Query("select jo from JobOrder jo order by jo.oid")
Stream<JobOrder> streamAll();
```

And wrap it with a transaction:

```java
@Repository
public class JobOrderTestDAO {
    @Autowired
    private JobOrderRepository repository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Stream<JobOrder> testGetAllByStream() {
        return repository.streamAll();
    }
}
```

Finally, in the test, I limit the stream size to 10 and print their `oid` in console. If `Cursor` is used as container, results should be returned immediately.

```java
@Autowired
private JobOrderTestDAO testDAO;

@Test
void testGetAllByStream() {
    Stream<JobOrder> joStream = testDAO.testGetAllByStream();
    joStream.limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
    joStream.close();
}
```

However, no results returned, only to find memory exploding. We checked the source code, EclipseLink seems not providing real-streaming solution for `getResultStream()` that said to "provide additional capabilities".

```java
default Stream<X> getResultStream() {
    return getResultList().stream();
}
```

Now we're using a somehow tricky workaround by downgrading JPA to 2.1.x. Since `StreamExecutor` will explicitly calling `Cursor` based function.

```
protected Object doExecute(final AbstractJpaQuery query, JpaParametersParameterAccessor accessor) {

    if (!SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.INSTANCE.isSurroundingTransactionActive()) {
        throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException(NO_SURROUNDING_TRANSACTION);
    }

    Query jpaQuery = query.createQuery(accessor);

    // JPA 2.2 on the classpath
    if (streamMethod != null) {
        return ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(streamMethod, jpaQuery);
    }

    // Fall back to legacy stream execution
    PersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = PersistenceProvider.fromEntityManager(query.getEntityManager());
    //Implementation here is using Cursor
    CloseableIterator<Object> iter = persistenceProvider.executeQueryWithResultStream(jpaQuery);

    return StreamUtils.createStreamFromIterator(iter);
}
```

It may not be a good practice to exclude a jar that match the versions and reinclude a jar that has been out of date. Thus, we are seeking for a solution, that might possibly keep `JpaRepository` and `JpaSpecificationExecutor` instead of coding directly with `ExpressionBuilder` and with stream underlying `Stream`.

Comment: Which database system are you using? Some JDBC drivers default to fetching all rows, and need to be explicitly configured not to do that.

Comment: We are using Oracle. @rotteveel

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue, what I found is that spring-data-jpa starting from 1.11.8 version changed implementation of JpaQueryExecution.doExecute. So instead of running persistenceProvider.executeQueryWithResultStream it calls Query.getResultStream method. The default implementation for getResultStream method is getResultList().stream(). That means that instead of real streaming and using scrollable cursors it tries to put all the data in memory. Eclipselink do not overrides default behavior for getResultStream method till current version 3.0.

A few options could be used here:

1. Instead of spring-data use directly JDBC like spring-data did on versions before 1.11.8.
2. Instead of eclipselink use hibernate or any other persistence provider who has full support of JPA 2.2 features.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm combining `@QueryHint(name = "eclipselink.cursor.scrollable", value = "true")` and return type `Cursor` or `Iterator<X>` and then convert them to a `Stream` as a workaround. Also extending `SimpleJpaRepository` to support stream with `Specification` as well.